# Why updated forge viewer's model browser isolate the items instead of select?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In the older version(7.1.*) of forge viewer the **Model** browser select the item and focus the selected item. [image: Older version of forge viewer select the items]

But in the latest version(7.*.*) it isolate the item(s).
[image: Latest forge viewer isolate the items]

**Is there any way or settings to get back to the older functionality in the latest version?**

Answer (score 2):

You can change the behavior by specifying options.docStructureConfig on ModelStructurePanel.

Pls. check below blog post and query on stack overflow which answering for this topics.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customizing-modelstructurepanel-behavior-forge-viewer

[Prevent zoom in Forge viewer when clicking in Model Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170849/prevent-zoom-in-forge-viewer-when-clicking-in-model-browser)

As described in the blog post, you can change the behavior by creating custom ModelStructure Panel on Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT handler or you can specify the option in its constructor.

You also can specify the option in GuiViewer3D constrictor like below.

```
var options = {
    docStructureConfig: {
        click: {
            onObject: ["selectOnly"] //instead of toggleOverlayedSelection
        },
        clickShift: {
            onObject: ["isolate"] //instead of toggleMultipleOverlayedSelection
        },
        clickCtrl: {
            onObject: ["selectToggle"] //instead of toggleMultipleOverlayedSelection
        }
    }
}
viewer3d = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer3d'), options);
```